# How to make request to get populated field in MongoDB with foreign key?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have shema:

```
const MessageSchema = new Schema(
  {
    parent: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Message', default: null },
    message: { type: String, default: '' },
    reply: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Message', default: null },
  }
);
```

I need to make some sort of simple chat with messages and comments to the messages. As I guess comment and message are actually the same schema. So if I create the message, not a comment to any message, I simply create it with parent 'null'. But if I create comment to the message I create document with parent with id of message I just commented.
So I want to get all comments of some message I just do mongo request like so

```
find({parent: <messageId>})
```

So for example I have collection:

```
   {
      _id: "ertgewrhyer436346rteyre"
      parent: null,
      message: 'I know the secret',
      reply: null
   },
   {
       _id: "dsgerwerg4w5jyjrt",
       parent: "ertgewrhyer436346rteyre"
       message: 'Ok',
       reply: null
    },
    {
       _id: "jmymesfhbuyt",
       parent: "ertgewrhyer436346rteyre"
       message: 'I need  to know too',
       reply: null
     },
     {
       _id: "5y46jyewrherhre",
       parent: "ertgewrhyer436346rteyre"
       message: 'Yes yes yes',
       reply: null
     }
```

But I don't know how make mongo request to return this:

```
{
    _id: "ertgewrhyer436346rteyre"
    parent: null,
    message: 'I know the secret',
    reply: [
     {
       parent: "ertgewrhyer436346rteyre",
       message: 'Ok',
       reply: null
     },
     {
       parent: "ertgewrhyer436346rteyre",
       message: 'I need  to know too',
       reply: null
     },
     {
       parent: "ertgewrhyer436346rteyre",
       message: 'Yes yes yes',
       reply: null
     }
    ],
  }
```

I know that I cat make field reply as array with ref: 'Message' but I think this is not good idea because there can be a lot of comments, and mongo have its limits.

Comment: you either need to use aggregation if you want exact same response directly from mongo or you can use simple find as you are doing and create reply array in your application.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track except setting up default value of parent and reply to null since the mongoose populate method will throw error when found field with null value. Either the field shouldn't exist, if it exist, it should be of type ObjectId.

Now, in order to populate your data, you can simply do this:

```
const result = await Model.find({}).populate('reply')
```

If you want to populate multiple fields, pass an array of strings and You'll be good